# Lost Wi-Fi after Ubuntu 16.04 laptop resumes from sleep

Tags: wireless, 16.04, network-manager, suspend

When done working on my laptop, I'll close the lid to put it to sleep.  After opening the lid, my Wi-Fi connection is often lost and zero APs are found in the network area in the upper right area within Unity.

Sometimes restarting NetworkManager with the following command will help, but I often have to reboot to reconnect to the network.

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

How can I get the wireless network connection to work after wake-up from suspension?

Comment: Hibernation (which is what you're doing) is handled through the files in `/etc/pm/`. See `man pm-powersave` for explanations.

Comment: To debug issues occurring during suspension or after wake-up, please [edit] your question and include the output of `sudo dmesg` and the content of `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` after a (potentially unsuccessful) suspend/wake-up cycle. For network issues it would also help to [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) after wake-up from suspension. Thanks.